# org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException union value '0000'

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I convert a **.docx** document with apache poi to **.pdf**, the word file is generated correctly with **docx4j**, but when i tried pass to PDF apache poi throws an exception:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: union value '00000' does not match any members of 'ST_HexColor in namespace http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlUnionImpl.set_text(XmlUnionImpl.java:154)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.update_from_wscanon_text(XmlObjectBase.java:1166)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_dated(XmlObjectBase.java:1305)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.isNil(XmlObjectBase.java:661)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.java_value(XmlObjectBase.java:2939)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.getObjectValue(XmlObjectBase.java:1669)
org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTColorImpl.getVal(Unknown Source)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.utils.ColorHelper.getColor(ColorHelper.java:65)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.run.RunFontColorValueProvider.getValue(RunFontColorValueProvider.java:42)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.run.RunFontColorValueProvider.getValue(RunFontColorValueProvider.java:33)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.run.AbstractRunValueProvider.getValueFromElement(AbstractRunValueProvider.java:76)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.run.AbstractRunValueProvider.getValueFromElement(AbstractRunValueProvider.java:44)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.AbstractValueProvider.internalGetValue(AbstractValueProvider.java:50)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.AbstractValueProvider.getValue(AbstractValueProvider.java:41)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.XWPFStylesDocument.getFontColor(XWPFStylesDocument.java:670)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitRun(PdfMapper.java:464)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitRun(PdfMapper.java:111)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitRuns(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:616)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitParagraphBody(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:441)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitParagraph(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:332)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitBodyElements(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:247)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.start(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:199)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:56)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:38)
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:45)
net.solsersistem.utils.pdf.PDFUtils.convertDocxToPDF(PDFUtils.java:24)
net.solser.admc.service.purchasingflow.PurchasingRequisitionService.sendFileToDownload(PurchasingRequisitionService.java:1173)
net.solser.admc.service.purchasingflow.PurchasingRequisitionService.sendFileToDownloadAndDeleteFile(PurchasingRequisitionService.java:1185)
net.solser.admc.service.purchasingflow.PurchasingRequisitionService.downloadDraftContract(PurchasingRequisitionService.java:347)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
net.solser.admc.filter.RequestSecurityFilter.doFilter(RequestSecurityFilter.java:48)
net.solser.filter.compress.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:35)
```

this exception is caused by .docx xml, not recognize the color tag. here an example:

```
<w:r>
     <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                <w:b w:val="false"/>
                <w:color w:val="00000"/>
                <w:sz w:val="21"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="21"/>
                <w:u w:val="none"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">313421</w:t>
        </w:r>
```

when i remove **w:color w:val="00000"** tag the pdf is generated.
the same situation when i try convert PDF with docx4j.

Any idea.

Tanks

Comment: Five digits color value looks strange. Should be `<w:color w:val="000000"/>`. Two digits red, two digits green, two digits blue.

Comment: So curious, the **.docx** file is generated with these values but the same docx4j plugin for pdf throws exception.

well, thanks, that's it

Comment: "So curious, the .docx file is generated with these values". So curious, which code is generating this? Almost nobody can using clairvoyance today. This extrasensory perception will only be possible after the big psi event in year 2035.